# Caddy - Setting HTTPS on local domain

Tags: https, localhost, caddy, caddyfile

I would like to add HTTPS to my local domain, however we can't do this on localhost.

My website goes fine when I run with this Caddyfile

```
localhost:2020 {
  bind {$ADDRESS}
  proxy / http://192.168.100.82:9000 {
    transparent
  }
}
```

But I would like to name this website or at least enable HTTPS on it. According to Caddy, you can't do this on localhost, but what if I have a domain name ?

I have tried using my own local address with this Caddyfile

```
192.168.100.26 {
  bind {$ADDRESS}
  proxy / http://192.168.100.82:9000 {
    transparent
  }
}
```

All works fine but I still don't have HTTPS...

And when I try to add a random domain name for example

```
www.mycaddytest.com {
  bind {$ADDRESS}
  proxy / http://192.168.100.82:9000 {
    transparent
  }
}
```

I got the following error

```
Activating privacy features...2016/08/18 11:53:26 [www.mycaddytest.com] failed to get certificate: acme: Error 400 - urn:acme:error:connection - DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for www.mycaddytest.com
Error Detail:
Validation for www.mycaddytest.com:80
Resolved to:

Used:
```

I know this error is dues to an unexisting domain name, but is there a way to deal with ?

Just getting HTTPS on localhost or ip address will be enough

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since Caddy 0.9 we can use the tls self_signed attribute.

Use this Caddyfile

```
localhost:2020 {
  bind {$ADDRESS}
  proxy / 192.168.100.82:9000
  tls self_signed
}
```

And try https://localhost:2020

Comment: The tls argument is no longer acceptable, see https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/tls

Comment: it has just been renamed to "internal" instead of "self_signed"

Answer (score 28):

For caddy version 2.4.5, the accepted answer did not work me. What worked is shown below:

```
localhost:443 {
        reverse_proxy 127.0.0.1:8080
        tls internal
}
```

Comment: An explanation for *why* this works would be useful

Answer (score 6):

I know that answer is already accepted. But I had the same problem with **Caddy v0.10.14** and it's a solution that helped me (but with real SSL certificate instead of self_signed):

1. Firstly, certificate & key pair must be in this directories: `/etc/pki/tls/certs/` for certificate and `/etc/pki/tls/private/` for key. So go to one of this directory with `cd` command
2. Then, create our own, self-signed certificate for HTTP2.0 testing with a single command, however. Just execute on your commandline to generate a SSL certificate + key pair:

`openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout cert.key -out cert.crt`

3. After that, move files to correct directories (see the first point)
4. Next, use this Caddyfile and try https://localhost:2020:

   ```
   localhost:2020 {
     bind {$ADDRESS}
     root /var/www
     gzip
     tls your.address@example.com
     tls /etc/pki/tls/certs/cert.crt /etc/pki/tls/private/cert.key
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Also if you are running caddy in a docker container, you may need to import and trust the Root certificate.

```
docker ps

docker cp container_id:/config/caddy/pki/authorities/local/root.crt ~/Desktop
```

then the caddyfile, for laravel sail for example, could look something like this:

```
yourlocaldomain.dev{
    tls internal
    reverse_proxy laravel.test
}
```

more may be here https://gilbitron.me/blog/enabling-https-ssl-for-laravel-sail-using-caddy/