# Caddy allow HTTP with Api Platform

Tags: api-platform.com, caddy, caddyfile

I know this question has been asked many times:

1. [Caddy - How to disable https only for one domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62896495/caddy-how-to-disable-https-only-for-one-domain)
2. [Disable caddy ssl to enable a deploy to Cloud Run through Gitlab CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66166642/disable-caddy-ssl-to-enable-a-deploy-to-cloud-run-through-gitlab-ci)
3. [Caddy - Setting HTTPS on local domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015159/caddy-setting-https-on-local-domain)
4. [How can I disable TLS when running from Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616944/how-can-i-disable-tls-when-running-from-docker)
5. [How to serve both http and https with Caddy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736121/how-to-serve-both-http-and-https-with-caddy)

but here is my problem.

## Setup

I created a new Api Platform project following their [documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution/).

> The easiest and most powerful way to get started is to download the [API Platform distribution](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/releases)

I downloaded the release [2.5.6](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/tree/v2.6.5) in which we can find:

- a [docker-compose](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/blob/v2.6.5/docker-compose.yml)
- a [Dockerfile](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/blob/v2.6.5/api/Dockerfile)
- a [Caddyfile](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/blob/v2.6.5/api/docker/caddy/Caddyfile)
- and many others files.

#### [docker-compose](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/blob/v2.6.5/docker-compose.yml)

I slightly change the docker compose file by removing the pwa service and PostgreSQL:

```yaml
version: "3.4"

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./api
      target: api_platform_php
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - api/.env
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s

  caddy:
    build:
      context: api/
      target: api_platform_caddy
    env_file:
      - api/.env
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
      MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: ${MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY:-!ChangeMe!}
      MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: ${MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY:-!ChangeMe!}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
    ports:
      # HTTP
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTPS
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTP/3
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        protocol: udp

volumes:
  php_socket:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
```

#### [Dockerfile](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/blob/v2.6.5/api/Dockerfile)

No changes

#### [Caddyfile](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/blob/v2.6.5/api/docker/caddy/Caddyfile)

Slight change by commenting the line `reverse_proxy @pwa http://{$PWA_UPSTREAM}`

```
{
    # Debug
    {$DEBUG}
    # HTTP/3 support
    servers {
        protocol {
            experimental_http3
        }
    }
}

{$SERVER_NAME}

log

# Matches requests for HTML documents, for static files and for Next.js files,
# except for known API paths and paths with extensions handled by API Platform
@pwa expression `(
        {header.Accept}.matches("\\btext/html\\b")
        && !{path}.matches("(?i)(?:^/docs|^/graphql|^/bundles/|^/_profiler|^/_wdt|\\.(?:json|html$|csv$|ya?ml$|xml$))")
    )
    || {path} == "/favicon.ico"
    || {path} == "/manifest.json"
    || {path} == "/robots.txt"
    || {path}.startsWith("/_next")
    || {path}.startsWith("/sitemap")`

route {
    root * /srv/api/public
    mercure {
        # Transport to use (default to Bolt)
        transport_url {$MERCURE_TRANSPORT_URL:bolt:///data/mercure.db}
        # Publisher JWT key
        publisher_jwt {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_ALG}
        # Subscriber JWT key
        subscriber_jwt {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_ALG}
        # Allow anonymous subscribers (double-check that it's what you want)
        anonymous
        # Enable the subscription API (double-check that it's what you want)
        subscriptions
        # Extra directives
        {$MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES}
    }
    vulcain
    push

    # Add links to the API docs and to the Mercure Hub if not set explicitly (e.g. the PWA)
    header ?Link `</docs.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation", </.well-known/mercure>; rel="mercure"`
    # Disable Google FLOC tracking if not enabled explicitly: https://plausible.io/blog/google-floc
    header ?Permissions-Policy "interest-cohort=()"

    # Comment the following line if you don't want Next.js to catch requests for HTML documents.
    # In this case, they will be handled by the PHP app.
    # reverse_proxy @pwa http://{$PWA_UPSTREAM}

    php_fastcgi unix//var/run/php/php-fpm.sock
    encode zstd gzip
    file_server
}
```

## Result

I can acccss my website on `https://localhost` but I can't access it without `https` because caddy [automatically redirect](https://caddyserver.com/docs/automatic-https#activation) `http` traffic to `https`

## Problem 1

When I try the solution `auto_https` it doesn't work.

Here what I tried:

- Adding the [`auto_https disable_redirects` or `auto_https off`](https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy/pull/3284)

```
{
    auto_https off
    # Debug
    {$DEBUG}
    # HTTP/3 support
    servers {
        protocol {
            experimental_http3
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

When I try to access `http://localhost:80`, I got redirect to `https://localhost` and I got `This site can’t provide a secure connection`

## Problem 2

When I try the [solution](https://caddyserver.com/docs/automatic-https#activation):

> Not providing any hostnames or IP addresses in the config

I remove `{$SERVER_NAME}` from my Caddyfile

When I try to access `http://localhost:80`, I got redirect to `https://localhost` and I got `This site can’t provide a secure connection`

## Problem 3

When I try the [solution](https://caddyserver.com/docs/automatic-https#activation):

> Listening exclusively on the HTTP port

```yaml
services:
  # ...
  caddy:
    build:
      context: api/
      target: api_platform_caddy
    #...
    ports:
      # HTTP
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTPS
      #- target: 443
      #  published: 443
      #  protocol: tcp
      # HTTP/3
      #- target: 443
      #  published: 443
      #  protocol: udp
```

When I try to access `http://localhost:80`, I got redirect to `https://localhost` and I got `This site can’t be reached`

## Question

How can I allow `http` on my caddy server (and still keep my configuration with mercure in my Caddyfile) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here:

https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy/issues/3219#issuecomment-608236439

#### Caddyfile

```
{
    http_port 8080
    # Debug
    {$DEBUG}
    # HTTP/3 support
    servers {
        protocol {
            experimental_http3
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

#### docker-compose

```yaml
services:
  caddy:
    # ...
    ports:
      # HTTP
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTPS
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTP/3
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        protocol: udp
```

Comment: It's not working for me, do you know how to make it work on the last api-platform template?

Answer (score 1):

Using the api-platform template v3

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
services:
  caddy:
    environment:
      # SERVER_NAME: ${SERVER_NAME:-localhost}, caddy:80

      # allow a page with http on different port.
      SERVER_NAME: localhost:443, http://localhost:8080/page.php, caddy:80

      # allow http completely on port 80.
      SERVER_NAME: localhost:443, localhost:80
    ports:
      # HTTP
      - target: 80
        published: ${HTTP_PORT:-80}
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTP Legacy
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTPS
      - target: 443
        published: ${HTTPS_PORT:-443}
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTP/3
      - target: 443
        published: ${HTTP3_PORT:-443}
        protocol: udp
```